# Parsing text file containing an list of JSON

Tags: python, json, regex, text

I have a directory that is frequently dumped a set of text files that look like:

- FILEA.json
- FILEB.json
- FILEC.json

Each file contains an 'array' of JSON that looks like this:

```
[
    {
       "id" : "blah",
       "type" : "thingy",
       "ip" : "10.0.0.1",
       "extended" : {
          "var1" : "blah"
        }
    },
    {
       "id" : "blah2",
       "type" : "thingy",
       "ip" : "10.0.0.2",
       "extended" : {
          "var1" : "blah"
        }
    }
]
```

I would like to know what would be the most efficient way for reading these files and storing each individual JSON string into an array for further processing. I have looked at [json.load()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html) but that seems to read in single JSON strings rather than an 'array' of strings.

One possible solution might be to strip the end brackets and split each JSON object via regex?

EDIT: Adding some example code:

```
    json_array = []
    for filename in sorted(os.listdir(CONFIG.DATA_DIR)):
        m = re.match('^.*\.JSON$', filename)
        if m:
            data = json.load(open(CONFIG.DATA_DIR+filename))
            for item in data:
                json_array.append(item)
    return json_array
```

Comment: JSON array is still a JSON object, no?

Comment: Read in all the files and build a list, then write it out?

Comment: Your sample json has four left curly brackets and only two right curly brackets. Is that intentional?

Comment: Why not read each file with `json.load()` and use the result to extend an initialy empty array? (provided they contain *correct* JSON...)

Comment: @Kevin - I've edited. Thanks for catch

Comment: Ok, cool :-) Now if you just delete the comma on the second-to-last line, `json.load` can read that data without any problems. Or are you saying "my file contains multiple instances of data like this, all concatenated together"? That's a little harder to fix.

Comment: I've edited and removed the errant comma and have also provided some example code. How would I go about parsing the individual 'objects' once I run json.load?

Answer (score 0):

You have illegally formatted JSON. You cannot have any stray commas, so I removed them with an expression below.

### Example

```
from json import dumps, loads
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join
from re import sub

'''This function transforms a directory of JSON array files and returns a 
   single-dimensional array of all of the items.
'''
def build_json_array(dir):
  result = []
  for f in listdir(dir):
    if isfile(join(dir, f)):
      with open(join(dir, f)) as json_data:
        json_text = sub(',\s+\]', ']', json_data.read()) # We need to repair the data
        result.extend(loads(json_text))
  return result

if __name__ == '__main__':
  print(dumps(build_json_array(CONFIG.DATA_DIR), indent=4))
```

> **Tip:** You can run your JSON data through a [Linter](https://jsonlint.com/) before loading and manipulating it.

If your JSON is formed correctly, you can simply load the data directly from the file.

```
from json import load

result.extend(load(json_data))
```

---

#### Code golf

Implemented a one-liner that utilizes list comprehension and reduces the arrays by flatting them.

```
from functools import reduce
from json import dumps, load
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join

def build_json_array(dir):
  return reduce(lambda x,y: x+y,(load(open(join(dir,f))) for f in listdir(dir) if isfile(join(dir,f))))
```

Comment: Hmm. Upon debugging, the contents of the array end up looking like:

["id", "type", "ip", "blah"....] instead of the entire JSON string, based on your suggestion of result.extend(load(json_data)) with well-formatted JSON

Comment: As for your Code Golf example, I get an error: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'dict' and 'dict'